# Best practice for calling remote rest services from a featherJS application

Tags: node.js, node-request, feathersjs

I need a way to call remote REST-APIs from my FeatherJS (NodeJS framework based on Express) application.

I have found several posts suggesting to use the request module which is fine: https://github.com/request/request

Are there any better suggestions now that I'm using FeatherJS? Or is the request module just fine?

Comment: I found a module called request-promise which seems a bit more convenient than module request.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend the `request-promise` module since Feathers services expect promises. Here is an example service [from this post how to make an existing API real-time](https://blog.feathersjs.com/using-feathersjs-to-make-your-existing-api-real-time-813f7c3fd892#.atja7rds7):

```
const feathers = require('feathers');
const rest = require('feathers-rest');
const socketio = require('feathers-socketio');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const handler = require('feathers-errors/handler');
const request = require('request-promise');

// A request instance that talks to the API
const makeRequest = request.defaults({
  baseUrl: 'https://todo-backend-rails.herokuapp.com',
  json: true
});

const todoService = {
  find(params) {
    return makeRequest(`/`);
  },

  get(id, params) {
    return makeRequest(`/${id}`);
  },

  create(data, params) {
    return makeRequest({
      uri: `/`,
      method: 'POST',
      body: data
    });
  },

  update(id, data, params) {
    // PATCH and update work the same here
    return this.update(id, data, params);
  },

  patch(id, data, params) {
    return makeRequest({
      uri: `/${id}`,
      method: 'PATCH',
      body: data
    });
  },

  remove(id, params) {
    // Retrieve the original Todo first so we can return it
    // The API only sends an empty body
    return this.get(id, params).then(todo => makeRequest({
      method: 'DELETE',
      uri: `/${id}`
    }).then(() => todo));
  }
};

// A normal Feathers application setup
const app = feathers()
  .use(bodyParser.json())
  .use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
  .configure(rest())
  .configure(socketio())
  .use('/todos', todoService)
  .use('/', feathers.static(__dirname))
  .use(handler());

app.listen(3030);
```

Comment: Thx I've come to the same conclusion. Unless there are other better alternatives I will mark this as the answer.